# How to display still 360 images in full screen like YouTube

Tags: google-cardboard, 360-degrees

I have to display 360 still images in my Android app. I want the exact same feature like YouTube's 360 video but for still images.
I am essentially lookin for the same functionality of full screen 360 and when clicked on cardboard button switch to cardboard view.
I want to use this in both modes as it will enable the user to choose whether to use the cardboard or not but still be able to move around and view everything.

I want the same features when you open [YouTube 360 example](https://youtu.be/aQd41nbQM-U)

I started reading from getting started for cardboard sdk for Android from [here](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started). It talks about using opengl and functionality of selection and updating the UI dynamically using opengl. I don't need those features, I only need to display static 360 images.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: 360 video or panorama image?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `VrPanoramaView`

https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/vrview

For the fullscreen, use `setDisplayMode`

```
panoWidgetView.setDisplayMode(VrVideoView.DisplayMode.FULLSCREEN_STEREO);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple to load a panorama image using the cardboard SDK. You need to just include a `VrPanoramaView` like this in your layout

```
<com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView
    android:id="@+id/pano_view"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="@null"
    android:layout_height="250dip" />
```

> Inside the Activity, the primary method is
>   VrPanoramaView.loadImageFromBitmap(). It is given a standard Android
>   Bitmap object and an optional VrPanoramaView.Options object. The
>   latter is used to configure the format of the image. The Activity also
>   implements a VrPanoramaEventListener which receives events when the
>   load operation succeeds or fails.

Quoted from the Getting Started [here](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started#vr_views_sample_apps).

---

Comment: Although I didn't mention it in the question above, but I am also looking for hotspots i.e. I can put some small icons on the panorama image and when clicked on those icons I move the user to a different panorama image. How can I do that? Hotspots are available in https://code.google.com/archive/p/panoramagl-android/